# Classifying a text into question or answer

Tags: classification, natural-language

I'm searching for a library or tool that allows me to classify emails of a mailing list into what mails are very likely questions and what mails are very likely answers.

Can anybody recommend such a tool?

Anything else than counting the fraction of question marks against periods?

Comment: since an e-mail can contain both questions and answeres, question mark alone seems to me a more precise classifier than any raw label assigned to a whole mail.

Comment: Thanks @carlo, than I can stop this project now finally after 6 years :D

Comment: you're welcome ahahah. don't know why but the question was active yesterday

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you can obtain a data set of emails annotated with the classification questions/answers, training a classifier for it (with e.g. a bag-of-words as features) would be quite straightforward.

In the absence of such annotated data sets, you might try to automatically derive a dataset by considering all first emails in a mailing list (i.e. with "Re: " in the title) as questions, and all direct answers to this email (and not from the initial author) as answers? This would only constitute a rough heuristic of course (there are certainly cases where that wouldn't work), but that's better than nothing.  You could then train a classifier from this data set, and evaluate its accuracy.